# How to push changes for an Octopress blog on GitHub?

Tags: ruby, github-pages, octopress

I've gone through the Octopress setup and deploy instructions, and I have Octopress running on Github:  http://wmerydith.github.com

My repo is set to the default branch of Master.

I now want to push changes to the config file,  like changing the url:, title: and subtitle:.  I made these changes, committed them, and then did a rake deploy, but the changes are not showing up.

What's unclear to me is the difference in process for pushing config changes, content changes and at some point, new updates to the Octopress blog.

For instance, will I use rake deploy to push config and content changes?

Will I ever need to run rake generate or rake deploy again?  How do I push source changes when Octopress updates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/github/), you might want to do a:

```
 rake generate
```

before the `rake deploy`.

> This will:
>
> - generate your blog,
> - copy the generated files into `_deploy/`,
> - add them to git,
> - commit and push them up to the `master` branch.
>
> In a few seconds you should get an email from Github telling you that your commit has been received and will be published on your site.

---

The [OP Will Merydith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535822/will-merydith) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12830148/how-to-push-changes-for-an-octopress-blog-on-github/12832838#comment17385785_12832838):

> I am unclear on is if '`rake deploy`' is enough to push content changes to the blog.
>   I'm seeing some issue with content not making it to the blog and am unclear if the error is how I am deploying or something else

I confirm the [Rakefile task :deploy](https://github.com/imathis/octopress/blob/master/Rakefile#L209-L216) will execute `default_deploy` which will execute [`task :push`](https://github.com/imathis/octopress/blob/master/Rakefile#L243-L260).

Comment: I got that far, but what I am unclear on is if 'rake deploy' is enough to push content changes to the blog.  I'm seeing some issue with content not making it to the blog and am unclear if the error is how I am deploying or something else.

Comment: @WillMerydith I have edited the answer to include reference to the source.

Comment: I have also trouble understanding what it is you need to do. For instance, from which branch do I run the rake tasks like rake new_post? On source or master? And after doing that, do I have to git push origin source first, or just rake generate && rake deploy?

Comment: @Matthias you do all that from the root directory of your octopress repo (the one you cloned from github.com/imathis/octopress.git): those tasks will take care of the right branch and pushing for you.

Comment: Not really: when I add a new post, then rake generate && rake deploy, I still have a pending change on source/_posts on the source branch. I still need to manually push that it seems?

Comment: @Matthias first, does the `rake watch` and `rake preview` work?

Comment: @Matthias from http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/github/, yes, you have to push (whether you are using `User/Organization` pages, or `gh-pages`)